# Scrolling and swiping in a PDF in Android

Tags: android

In my project I am rendering pdf, in landscape mode I am fitting to pagewidth and in portrait mode I am fitting to pageheight mode. How to do scrolling in landscape mode only and swiping in both orientations?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the easiest way of doing this, assuming the scrolling is defines in your XML, is to create different layouts for each. somename_land.xml in the layout-land folder would have scrolling defined while somename_port.xml in layout-port would not. Both would have swiping. You then select the context in your code with something like this:

```
WindowManager winMan = (WindowManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (winMan != null) {
    int orientation = winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();

    if (orientation == 0) {
        // Portrait
        setContentView(R.layout.somename_port.xml);
    } else if (orientation == 1) {
        // Landscape
        setContentView(R.layout.somename_land.xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you cameron but in my project i am not using different layouts instead i am using onconfigurationchanged  method and in that method i am setting to page width  or page height.

Comment: Well your code will be messier, but your onConfigurationChanged method you can use if (orientation == 1) and replace setContentView with the code needed to create the vertical scrolling. Since you want horizontal scrolling either way, just define it outside of the if statement. I would recommend the XML route though